# how do "relocate" cell values in a single column to a single row using Offset?

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am a bad VBA person. Please help me.

I want to relocate three values in a single column and put them in a single row using Offset.  I need to flatten 3 rows of data into a single row of data.

Here is the code - it's very crude:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    'turn off display update
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim CVFESUMMARY2(2000, 2000)
Dim MAXROW As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range
Dim z As Range

Set r = Range("BJ13:BJ512")
Set x = Range("BK13:BK512")
Set y = Range("BL13:BL512")
Set z = Range("BM13:BM512")

MAXROW = 300

'format "new" columns

Range("BK11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NORM"

Range("BL11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MIN"

Range("BM11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MAX"

Columns("BJ:BM").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 12

'define the "COPY DATA FROM" starting cell location

Sheets("CVFESUMMARY2").Select
Range("BJ13").Select

'cycle through all of the rows in range r
For i = 1 To MAXROW

        'copy "BJ13"
        r.Select
        Selection.Copy

        'paste "value only" in column "BK13"
        x.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        'copy "BJ13+1"
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
        r.Select
        Selection.Copy

        'paste "value only" in column "BL13"
        y.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        'copy "BJ13+2"
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
        r.Select
        Selection.Copy

        'paste "value only" in column "BM13"
        z.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        'move active cell to "BJ13+4"
        Set r = r.Offset(2, 0)

        Set x = x.Offset(4, 0)
        Set y = y.Offset(4, 0)
        Set z = z.Offset(4, 0)
Next i

'turn on display update
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This somewhat works but it is adding values in rows +2 and +3 that I don't want; I think the looping is wrong. Thanks in advance!

**Before**

[image: Example of data before transformation]

**After**

[image: Example of data after transformation]

Comment: Your question is a little confusing (after reading it, and the code; but this could just be me!). Would you be able to add some screenshots showing before and after of what your trying to do?

Comment: Please use http://imageshack.us/ or any similar sites to upload screenshots then edit your question and add the link to your screenshots. I think you need `10` points to upload images directly into `stackoverflow` question.

Comment: You can if you want, (me at nickslash.co.uk) but ideally you could upload them images to imgur.com (or similar) and edit your post to include the links so everyone can see them.

Comment: [url=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/716/captureafter.png/][img=http://imageshack.us/a/img716/7215/captureafter.png][/url]

Comment: [url=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/capturebefore.png/][img=http://imageshack.us/a/img833/3521/capturebefore.png][/url]

Comment: aha! I figured it out! The Range definitions were wrong; I was moving the entire Range around. Changed the code to:Set r = Range("BJ13") Set x = Range("BK13") Set y = Range("BL13") Set z = Range("BM13") and it works. Now, how do I eliminate the rows that were "flattened"?

Comment: You can use `paste with transpose` It can change row values to column values. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output, can the results be compacted? (all empty rows removed, leaving a block of data) or is there information in the columns before that its linked with?

Removing the extra rows wouldn't be much extra work.

With the following code (which I think does what you want) the `MaxRows` value is incorrect. The way it works this should be a `MaxRecords` ie: the number of groups of data you.

```
Sub Transpose()
Dim Position As Range
Dim Source As Range
Dim MaxRow As Integer
Dim Index As Integer

' set column titles
Range("BK11").Value2 = "NORM"
Range("BL11").Value2 = "MIN"
Range("BM11").Value2 = "MAX"

' set the width
Range("BJ:BM").ColumnWidth = 12

MaxRow = 512 ' see note below

Set Position = Range("BJ13") ' define the start position

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'For Index = 1 To MaxRow
Do

    ' create a range that contains your first 3 values    
    Set Source = Range(Position, Position.Offset(RowOffset:=2))
    ' copy it
    Source.Copy
    ' paste and transpose the values into the offset position
    Position.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    ' OPTIONAL - Clear the contents of your source range
    Source.ClearContents 
    ' re-set the position ready for the next iteration
    Set Position = Position.Offset(RowOffset:=4)

'Next
Loop While Position.Row < RowMax

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Note: I've not used `Select` and `Selection` as they confuse me! Using `Range()` makes it simpler to know where you are imo.

**Update** I've included one that also compacts the output

```
Sub TransposeCompact()
Dim Position As Range
Dim Source As Range
Dim Destination As Range
Dim MaxRow As Integer
Dim Index As Integer

' set column titles
Range("BK11").Value2 = "NORM"
Range("BL11").Value2 = "MIN"
Range("BM11").Value2 = "MAX"

' set the width
Range("BJ:BM").ColumnWidth = 12

MaxRow = 512 ' see note below

' define the start position
Set Position = Range("BJ13")
' define the first output position
Set Destination = Position.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'For Index = 1 To MaxRow
Do

    ' create a range that contains your first 3 values
    Set Source = Range(Position, Position.Offset(RowOffset:=2))
    ' copy it
    Source.Copy
    ' paste and transpose the values into the offset position
    Destination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    ' OPTIONAL - Clear the contents of your source range
    Source.ClearContents
    ' re-set the position ready for the next iteration
    Set Position = Position.Offset(RowOffset:=4)
    ' increment the row on the output for the next iteration
    Set Destination = Destination.Offset(RowOffset:=1)

'Next
Loop While Position.Row < RowMax

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

**Update 2**
Your `i` variable used in the `For Loop` is not actually used, if your data is in rows 13 to 512 then the edits I've made to the code above should help.

The `RowMax` variable now will stop the macro when `Position.Row` goes beyond it.

Comment: Thank you Nick! I will give it a whirl. Would you show me how to delete "unused" rows, please? This routine eliminates the need for the 2 rows under the new "combined" row. Thanks again! It's great that there are people who will help you.

Comment: The second example `TransposeCompact` removes the need to delete rows as it puts the output on a specific row. If you want a blank row between each line you will need to modify the `RowOffset` in the last line of the `Do Loop`. (Change 1 to 2)

Comment: You could also remove the old `NORM`, `MIN` and `MAX` by Doing `Source.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).ClearContents` inside the loop. If I've answered your question could you accept the answer please :)